# Jquery Cycle plugin. Command Prev not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble getting the Jquery Cycle plugin to work. My code is below. Whats happening is the Next button is going through the slides sequentially, however when I press previous, it goes previous starting from the last image in the sequence. I dont want it to automaticly play which is why on my document.ready function I call the pause command.

Any help will be appreciated.

-Sam

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.main').cycle({
            fx : 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        });

        $(".main").cycle("pause");

    });

</script>

 // extra page code not shown //


    <div class="main" id="main">
        <img src="../images/design/beautiful1.jpg" height=600 width=500>
        <img  src="../images/design/beautiful2.jpg" height=600 width=500>
        <img  src="../images/design/beautiful3.jpg" height=600 width=500>
        <img  src="../images/design/beautiful4.jpg" height=600 width=500>

    </div>


</body>

<div class="label" id="nextbutton"><img src="../images/nextarrow.jpg"></div>
<div class="label" id="prevbutton"><img src="../images/prevarrow.jpg"></div>

<script>

      $("#nextbutton").live("click",function(){

                $(".main").cycle("next");

        }


     );

       $("#prevbutton").live("click",function(){

                $(".main").cycle("prev");

        }


     );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/4f2hx/

Comment: Thanks, I realized there was an issue with my CSS causing the prev button to overal the next one!